# Creating buttons/href from a list of names on the server side with javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a list of button names and uri's containing links to other pages in my website. This is stored in my database. I also have a javascript function that can create buttons dynamically preferably when the page loads. Now what I need is on the server side to iterate through the list of button names and create a button for every button in the list?

Is this possible. I was thinking of maybe using the string builder to build some html to create the buttons or the method I like more is to call the javascript everytime I need a new button.

Here is my javascript function:

```
    function createHref(Name, Uri) {
        var leftDiv = document.createElement("div"); //Create left div
        leftDiv.id = "left"; //Assign div id
        leftDiv.setAttribute("style", "float:left; width:66.5%; line-height: 26px;       text-align:left; font-size:12pt; padding-left:8px; height:26px;"); //Set div attributes
        leftDiv.style.background = "#FF0000";
        a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = Uri;
        a.innerHTML = Name
        leftDiv.appendChild(a);
        document.body.appendChild(leftDiv);
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to build the buttons on the server? How to send the data to Javascript to do it? Or a comparison of the two?

Comment: As stated the above, I am basically looking for a solution that will build my buttons dynamically either using some type of sting builder and injecting the html into the client side, or calling a javascript function from the server side that will create the buttons. Either by sending the list of items to the javacript function or iterating through the list on the server side and executing the function each time on the server side. Some one with more experience could tell me which is the easiest way to do it, possibly with a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is ASP.NET I would use a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) and set the datasource to the button data you pull from your database.

For examples sake, I will assume you have a custom object `MyButton` that maps to your data:

```
public class MyButton
{
     public MyButton()
     {}

     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Href { get; set; }
}
```

You would then have some markup for the repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMyButtons" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptMyButtons_ItemDataBound">
   <HeaderTemplate>
       <ul>
   </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
               <asp:HyperLink ID="hypUrl" runat="server" />
            </li>
       </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
       </ul>
   </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

You would then bind your data to the repeater and set some properties on the objects:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if(!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
           rptMyButtons.DataSource = //your data from the database
           rptMyButtons.DataBind();
      }
 }

protected void rptMyButtons_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
         MyButton button = (MyButton)e.Item.DataItem;
         HyperLink hypUrl = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("hypUrl");
         hypUrl.Text = button.Name;
         hypUrl.NavigateUrl = button.Href;
    }
}
```

It seems like you may be trying to build a sitemap?

> I have a list of button names and uri's containing links to other pages in my website

Which is why I have used a `<ul>` and `<li>`'s to contain your buttons in a list which makes more sense. It is quite easy to change this back to a `<div>` however.